# How can we implement singleten design pattern in iphone code

Tags: iphone

I want to implement singleten design pattern in iphone code

I have one array. I want it to retain its value between function calls of from single class function.

How Can I use singleten design pattern to do above task?
Thanks.

Comment: Is there any sample code availlable ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

better you can initialize it in appdelegate of your project.
then you can access this array anywhere in your project.

```
#define UIAppDelegate ((yourAppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate)
```

include this in your your appDelegate, then you can access your array any where you want.

```
UIAppDelegate.yourArray
```

Answer (score 1):

Matt Gallagher has a pretty good writeup, with a very simple to use preprocessor macro to set create a singleton for class:

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/11/singletons-appdelegates-and-top-level.html